# Testing Python console scripts in development

Tags: python, testing

I'm working on a Python package that comes with a few console scripts. Because of how the package is laid out (see ex. below), the console scripts don't see the package they're trying to import from.

Here's an example layout:

```
- my_package
    bin/some_script.py
    my_package/
      __init__.py
      a_module.py
```

How should I structure the package so that I can test the console scripts in "bin" while working on the Python package's contents?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little trick.

```
python < bin/some_script.py
```

where `bin/some_script.py` imports from `my_package` will import from the development directory.

This assumes that you use some sort of bash-like shell where `<` works as input redirection.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and finally I've ended up doing this in the beginning of my script:

```
try:
    # this works after package has been installed using distutils for example
    import my_package
except ImportError:
    # this should work during dev time with the directory layout you describe
    rootpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(__file__, "../")))
    sys.path.insert(0, rootpath)
    try:
        import my_package
    except ImportError:
        print("*** my_package is not installed properly. Exiting.")
        sys.exit()
```

And so now I can execute the console script from the project root:

```
bin/some_script.py --help
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'bin'))
```

so, inside `__init__.py`

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'bin'))

import some_script

some_script.some_function()
```